# How to design a circular view from bottom?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I am trying to design a view which is circular from bottom, please see the image 
[image]

> I have try different way to design, Like XML, Programatically but I am not able to get any success. I use XML code it's doing circle from bottom but when I use Any image or Banner slider as show in figure then it's hold whole view.

Right now I am using this code XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_radius"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ss.com.bannerslider.views.BannerSlider
        android:id="@+id/bannerSlider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And `bottom_radius.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="4dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

The out put is coming like that in XML 
[image]

> The XML output is looks good as I expected, but when I run the program and see the out put on the mobile or simulator then output is looks like

[image]

> Please provide me solution so that I can design what I want to design. I will be very thank full to you.

Comment: well i tried your code , its not the curved

Comment: The quick and dirty approach is to put the white part outside the circle below the image on top of the rectangular image. This will cause an overdraw (and for that reason is not optimal) but should work.

Comment: @Henry, Please provide me the solution, How I can achieve this thing because I have already spend many time on that.

Answer (score 1):

put the `android:background="@drawable/bottom_radius"` to the image instead of `linearlayout`

Comment: Kurusu, Thanks for giving me your suggestions, But it's not working

Answer (score 0):

**make an drawable file.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/colorPrimary"
        />
    <padding android:left="1dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp"
        />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="150dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="150dp"
        />
</shape>
```

**and then set it to background of your main layout**

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`PorterDuff.Mode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html) class. It let's the developer combine two bitmaps in a number of different ways. We will use the Porter-Duff mode `PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN` below.

The following is a short demo of how to produce the result that you are looking for. First, here is the result:

[image]

We will use the image below to crop the photo to the shape we want using the Porter-Duff mode `PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN`. Once applied using the Porter-Duff mode, the non-transparent areas will be retained in the destination bitmap (our photo) and pixels in the photo that correspond to transparent pixels of the image below will be tossed.

[image]

Now that the photo is cropped, we will apply the yellow border using the image below. (The yellow border in the cropping bitmap shown above is not really used. It is just important that the alpha values of all pixels in the yellow area are 1.0.) This image has the same dimensions as the previous image but the transparent area also include the area above the yellow arc. This drawable will simply be drawn on top of the image.

[image]

Here is the code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView topImage = findViewById(R.id.bottomImage);
        topImage.setImageBitmap(cropAndOverlay(topImage, R.drawable.smile,
                                               R.drawable.smile_transparent));
    }

    private Bitmap cropAndOverlay(@NonNull ImageView imageView,
                                  @DrawableRes int cropId, @DrawableRes int overlayId) {
        // Get the bitmap for the current image.
        Bitmap dst = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

        // Get the cropping image. This is the Porter-Duff source image.
        Bitmap src = Bitmap.createBitmap(dst.getWidth(), dst.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas resultCanvas = new Canvas(src);
        Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), cropId, null);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, resultCanvas.getWidth(), resultCanvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(resultCanvas);

        // Combine the source with the destination bitmap while applying the Porter-Duff mode.
        Bitmap resultBitmap = getPorterDuffBitmap(dst, src, PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN);
        resultCanvas.setBitmap(resultBitmap);

        // Place the overlay image on the bitmap.
        drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), overlayId, null);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, resultBitmap.getWidth(), resultBitmap.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(resultCanvas);
        dst.recycle();
        return resultBitmap;
    }

    private Bitmap getPorterDuffBitmap(Bitmap dst, Bitmap src, PorterDuff.Mode mode) {
        Bitmap bitmap =
            Bitmap.createBitmap(dst.getWidth(), dst.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        // Draw the original bitmap (DST)
        canvas.drawBitmap(dst, 0, 0, null);

        // Draw the mask (SRC) with the specified Porter-Duff mode
        Paint maskPaint = new Paint();
        maskPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(mode));
        canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, maskPaint);

        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

And the XML:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:background="#b1a8a8"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bottomImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/photo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I presented this in the main activity, but the technique would probably be better applied in a custom view.